# Telegram NDK build : Command not found

Tags: android, android-ndk, cygwin, telegram

I have followed the steps mention in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33765946/android-telegram-app-java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-no-implementation-found) to run the Telegram github project in android studio 1.5.1. When I try to run the ndkbuild command in cygwin terminal but I got command not found message in the cygwin terminal, Please check the screenshot of my cygwin terminal and I'm able to list the file in jni folder also I have added the below command in the bashrc file

export ndkbuild=/cygdrive/c/android-ndk-r10e/ndk-build.cmd

but it's not working, Please let me know where I have done wrong.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: **1.** open cygwin shell window **2.** type `export ndkbuild=/cygdrive/c/android-ndk-r10e/ndk-build.cmd`<enter> **3.** type `$ndkbuild`<enter>.

Comment: I have done it but again I'm getting same issue, please check the screenshot and also I'm new to this.

Comment: You forgot the $ before command. Nevermind. On command line, you can simply type the full path

Comment: I have added the $ but now it says that $ $ndkbuild
Android NDK: Could not find application project directory !
Android NDK: Please define the NDK_PROJECT_PATH variable to point to it.
C:\android-ndk-r10e\build/core/build-local.mk:143: *** Android NDK: Aborting    .  Stop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I have found the answer after referring many stackoverflow link

I have downloaded the ndk and extract it in the folder.

And opened the android studio terminal, navigated to ndk folder.

finally I ran the following command
ndk-build -C xxxxxxx\Telegram-master\TMessagesProj\jni

and it gets compiled and I have executed the github telegram project.

Comment: please provide the steps of making lib from jni.