# How to compile telegram jni folder

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface, telegram

I am trying to compile jni folder in telegram source code in [github.com/DrKLO/Telegram/](http://github.com/DrKLO/Telegram/) with ndk

But when i am write ndk-build in cmd in ndk folder
like:

> F:\ndk\android-ndk-r10>ndk-build -C F:\Workspace\Android\Telegram-master-1-12-2016\Telegram-master\TMessagesProj\jni

I get some error and libs folder not created

When i add ndk path to android studio and add jni folder manually android studio say can not find some header files

Following this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33765946/android-telegram-app-java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-no-implementation-found) download [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/) and use it, but again get this error like ndk-build

```
$ndkbuild
```

> [armeabi] SharedLibrary  : libtmessages.15.so
>
> process_begin: CreateProcess(........,
>
> F:/ndk/android-ndk-r10/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.8/libs/armeabi 
>        /thumb/libgnustl_static.a -lgcc -no-canonical-prefixes
>        -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-z ,noexecstack -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now
>        -LF:/ndk/android-ndk-r10/platforms/android-
>         9/arch-arm/usr/lib -ljnigraphics -llog -lz -ldl -lc -lm -o
>        F:/Workspace/Android/
>        Telegram-master-1-12-2016/Telegram-master/TMessagesProj//obj/local/armeabi/libtm
>        essages.15.so, ...) failed
>
> make (e=87): The parameter is incorrect.
>
> make.exe: *** [F:/Workspace/Android/Telegram-master-1-12-2016/Telegram-master/TMessagesProj//obj/local/armeabi/libtmessages.15.so] Error 87

How fix this?

Comment: For *some* error you need *some* fix.

Comment: Often, switching to Cygwin for NDK build creates more problems than it resolves. Which errors did you see with the first (**ndk-build.cmd** - based) attempt? Use `ndk-build V=1` to display all the actual commands as they unwrap.

Comment: @AlexCohn  fatal error: sys/ucontext.h: No such file or directory

Comment: If you used `V=1`, you have the command that caused this *fatal error*, please post it

Comment: @AlexCohn [ndk-build output here](http://s13.postimg.org/az8k72mo7/2016_01_13_6_45_04.png)

Comment: My NDK (r10d) has file `platforms/android-9/arch-arm/usr/include/sys/ucontext.h`; what about your `F:\ndk\android-ndk-r10\platforms\android-9\arch-arm\usr\include\sys\ucontext.h`?

Comment: @AlexCohn ucontext.h file not in sys folder, i am download ndk from android developer but why not complete?

Comment: Maybe you need to reinstall NDK, maybe also download it again from 
https://dl.google.com/android/ndk/android-ndk-r10e-windows-x86_64.exe

Comment: @AlexCohn thanks. compile finish successfully

Comment: @AlexCohn I use your comment syntax and my build complete successfully thank u man.

Answer (score 15):

Important update issue:
in 3.18 version, after downloading telegram source project, if you go to jni folder you will find and empty folder named libtgvoip, to fill it with needed files:
1- go to telegram source from githum, goto jni folder and click on libtgvoip @ eb813e1 folder (@ means that this is a refrence folder).
2- download that library too!
3- copy its content in empty folder discussed earlier!

Now lets begin:
Its very easy.

1- Add NDK directory to environment PATH variable.

2- open Android.mk and add the following line:
LOCAL_SHORT_COMMANDS := true

[image]

3- open Application.mk and add the following line:
APP_SHORT_COMMANDS := true

[image]

4- open command prompt as administrator and navigate to jni folder like this:
(important: in last version of telegram you should navigate to jni parent folder instead of jni folder)

[image]

5- just execute ndk-build command

[image]

Then ndk will start building .so files:

[image]

wait until it finish the task, maybe some warnings displayed but not important. finally you will have all shared library (.so files) in the obj directory:
(important: in last version of telegram .so files will create in lib folder and everything is ready to build)

[image]

then goto each of these folders and delete everything except libtmessages.22.so.
create a libs folder and copy that three directory into it:

[image]

Build and have fun! (remember to fill out variables in org.telegram.messenger.BuildVars class with your app id and app_hash. [read more here](https://github.com/DrKLO/Telegram))

Comment: You don't really need `LOCAL_SHORT_COMMANDS := true` in the Android.mk file because `APP_SHORT_COMMANDS := true` already covers all modules. See [here](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/application_mk.html)

Comment: I just done all of this but get this error and do not know what to do:

Error:org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 0; columnNumber: 0; cvc-pattern-valid: Value 'extras;intel - Copy;Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager' is not facet-valid with respect to pattern '[a-zA-Z0-9_\-;.]+' for type 'segmentListType'.

plz help me

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the object file.
This error most likely appeared after the previous build was interrupted and object file was not generated completely.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Download the android-ndk Then go to the Project directory (./TMessagesProj) and execute ndk-build.
Then re-run the gradle build which packages the native libs into the apk.

Comment: Can you add link from where it can be downloaded

Comment: This is my build process https://www.jianshu.com/p/dc9491d537d7，The file is too big for me to go to Sichuan