# make: *** [*/TMessagesProj/obj/local/armeabi/libtmessages.22.so] Error 87

Tags: android-ndk, cygwin, telegram

I have followed the steps mention in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33765946/android-telegram-app-java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-no-implementation-found) to run the Telegram github project in android studio . When I try to run the ndkbuild command in cygwin terminal but I got the 87 error message : Error message Please let me know where I have done wrong.

[image]

rocess_begin: CreateProcess(C:\android-ndk-r10e\toolchains\arm-linux-androideab i-4.9\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\arm-linux-androideabi-g++.exe, C:/android-ndk- r10e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/arm-linux- androideabi-g++ -Wl,-soname,libtmessages.22.so -shared --sysroot=C:/android-ndk- r10e/platforms/android-9/arch-arm C:/Android_develper/Telegram/Source/Telegram-m aster/Telegram-master/TMessagesProj/obj/local/armeabi/objs/tmessages.22/./opus/s rc/opus.o C:/Android_develper/Telegram/Source/Telegram-master/Telegram-master/TM essagesProj/obj/local/armeabi/objs/tmessages.22/./opus/src/opus_decoder.o C:/And . . . . . aster/TMessagesProj/jni/./boringssl/lib/libcrypto_armeabi.a C:/android-ndk-r10e/ sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/libs/armeabi/thumb/libgnustl_static.a -lgcc -n o-canonical-prefixes -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,n ow -LC:/android-ndk-r10e/platforms/android-9/arch-arm/usr/lib -ljnigraphics -llo g -lz -latomic C:/android-ndk-r10e/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/libs/armeab i/libsupc++.a -ldl -lc -lm -o C:/Android_develper/Telegram/Source/Telegram-maste r/Telegram-master/TMessagesProj/obj/local/armeabi/libtmessages.22.so, ...) faile d. make (e=87): ▒Ѽƿ▒▒~▒C make.exe: *** [C:/Android_develper/Telegram/Source/Telegram-master/Telegram-mast er/TMessagesProj/obj/local/armeabi/libtmessages.22.so] Error 87

Comment: may be a better fomatting to understand what is the error ?

Comment: thanks,the question edited

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error message while attempting to compile on Windows using Cygwin. Turns out you don't need to use Cygwin. The answer posted by [farhad.kargaran at the following link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34745704/how-to-compile-telegram-jni-folder#) resolved the issue for me:

Comment: Please put the essintial parts of the linked content to your answer directly

Comment: Thanks but give same error(error 87) in command prompt as administrator