# Android Telegram compiling error

Tags: android, android-ndk, telegram, ndk-build

I'm trying to develop with the new Telegram source code, but when debugging, I got this error. I have put API, Hockey API, and have tried by following https://stackoverflow.com/a/34323758/7531970, but I am not finding any luck. Please help. Thank You

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:TMessagesProj:assembleArmv7Debug]
Information:(Unknown) In file included
Information:(Unknown)
Information:(Unknown)
Error:error: redefinition of 'struct r_debug'
Information:(Unknown) In file included
Error:error: redefinition of 'struct link_map'
Error:error: redefinition of 'struct r_debug'
Error:error: redefinition of 'struct link_map'
E:\ANDROIDPROJECTS\Android\AndroidSDK\ndk-bundle\sysroot\usr\include\link.h
Error:(77, 8) error: previous definition of 'struct r_debug'
Error:(68, 8) error: previous definition of 'struct link_map'
Error:(77, 8) error: previous definition of 'struct r_debug'
Error:(68, 8) error: previous definition of 'struct link_map'
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 4 mins 43.334 secs
Information:8 errors
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console

Console Output

In file included from ./jni/breakpad/client/linux/minidump_writer/linux_dumper.h:43:0,
from ./jni/breakpad/client/linux/minidump_writer/minidump_writer.h:41,
from E:/Telegram/TMessagesProj/jni/./breakpad/client/linux/handler/exception_handler.h:42,
from E:/Telegram/TMessagesProj/jni/./NativeLoader.cpp:3:
./jni/breakpad/common/android/include/link.h:46:8: error: redefinition of 'struct r_debug'
struct r_debug {
^
In file included from ./jni/breakpad/common/android/include/link.h:35:0,
from ./jni/breakpad/client/linux/minidump_writer/linux_dumper.h:43,
from ./jni/breakpad/client/linux/minidump_writer/minidump_writer.h:41,
from E:/Telegram/TMessagesProj/jni/./breakpad/client/linux/handler/exception_handler.h:42,
from E:/Telegram/TMessagesProj/jni/./NativeLoader.cpp:3:
e:\androidprojects\android\androidsdk\ndk-bundle\sysroot\usr\include\link.h:77:8: error: previous definition of 'struct r_debug'
struct r_debug {
^
In file included from ./jni/breakpad/client/linux/minidump_writer/linux_dumper.h:43:0,
from ./jni/breakpad/client/linux/minidump_writer/minidump_writer.h:41,
from E:/Telegram/TMessagesProj/jni/./breakpad/client/linux/handler/exception_handler.h:42,
from E:/Telegram/TMessagesProj/jni/./NativeLoader.cpp:3:
./jni/breakpad/common/android/include/link.h:57:8: error: redefinition of 'struct link_map'
struct link_map {
^
In file included from ./jni/breakpad/common/android/include/link.h:35:0,
from ./jni/breakpad/client/linux/minidump_writer/linux_dumper.h:43,
from ./jni/breakpad/client/linux/minidump_writer/minidump_writer.h:41,
from E:/Telegram/TMessagesProj/jni/./breakpad/client/linux/handler/exception_handler.h:42,
from E:/Telegram/TMessagesProj/jni/./NativeLoader.cpp:3:
e:\androidprojects\android\androidsdk\ndk-bundle\sysroot\usr\include\link.h:68:8: error: previous definition of 'struct link_map'
struct link_map {
^
make: *** [E:/Telegram/TMessagesProj/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/armv7/debug/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs-debug/tmessages.26/./NativeLoader.o] Error 1
:TMessagesProj:externalNativeBuildArmv7Debug FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':TMessagesProj:externalNativeBuildArmv7Debug'.
Build command failed.
Error while executing process E:\ANDROIDPROJECTS\Android\AndroidSDK\ndk-bundle\ndk-build.cmd with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=E:\Telegram\TMessagesProj\jni\Android.mk NDK_APPLICATION_MK=E:\Telegram\TMessagesProj\jni\Application.mk APP_ABI=armeabi-v7a NDK_ALL_ABIS=armeabi-v7a NDK_DEBUG=1 APP_PLATFORM=android-14 NDK_OUT=E:/Telegram/TMessagesProj/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/armv7/debug/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=E:\Telegram\TMessagesProj\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\armv7\debug\lib NDK_APPLICATION_MK:=jni/Application.mk APP_PLATFORM:=android-14 E:/Telegram/TMessagesProj/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/armv7/debug/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libtmessages.26.so}
[armeabi-v7a] Compile arm : tmessages.26 <= opus.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile arm : tmessages.26 <= opus_decoder.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile arm : tmessages.26 <= opus_encoder.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile arm : tmessages.26 <= opus_multistream.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile arm : tmessages.26 <= opus_multistream_encoder.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile arm : tmessages.26 <= opus_multistream_decoder.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile arm : tmessages.26 <= repacketizer.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile arm : tmessages.26 <= analysis.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile arm : tmessages.26 <= mlp.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile arm : tmessages.26 <= mlp_data.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile arm : tmessages.26 <= CNG.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile arm : tmessages.26 <= code_signs.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile arm : tmessages.26 <= init_decoder.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile arm : tmessages.26 <= decode_core.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile arm : tmessages.26 <= decode_frame.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile arm : tmessages.26 <= decode_parameters.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile arm : tmessages.26 <= decode_indices.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile arm : tmessages.26 <= decode_pulses.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile arm : tmessages.26 <= decoder_set_fs.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile arm : tmessages.26 <= dec_API.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile arm : tmessages.26 <= enc_API.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile arm : tmessages.26 <= encode_indices.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile arm : tmessages.26 <= encode_pulses.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile arm : tmessages.26 <= gain_quant.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile arm : tmessages.26 <= interpolate.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile arm : tmessages.26 <= LP_variable_cutoff.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile arm : tmessages.26 <= NLSF_decode.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile arm : tmessages.26 <= NSQ.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile arm : tmessages.26 <= NSQ_del_dec.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile arm : tmessages.26 <= PLC.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile arm : tmessages.26 <= shell_coder.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile arm : tmessages.26 <= tables_gain.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile arm : tmessages.26 <= tables_LTP.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile arm : tmessages.26 <= tables_NLSF_CB_NB_MB.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile arm : tmessages.26 <= tables_NLSF_CB_WB.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile arm : tmessages.26 <= tables_other.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile arm : tmessages.26 <= tables_pitch_lag.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile arm : tmessages.26 <= tables_pulses_per_block.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile arm : tmessages.26 <= VAD.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile arm : tmessages.26 <= control_audio_bandwidth.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile arm : tmessages.26 <= quant_LTP_gains.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile arm : tmessages.26 <= VQ_WMat_EC.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile arm : tmessages.26 <= HP_variable_cutoff.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile arm : tmessages.26 <= NLSF_encode.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile arm : tmessages.26 <= NLSF_VQ.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile arm : tmessages.26 <= NLSF_unpack.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile arm : tmessages.26 <= NLSF_del_dec_quant.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile arm : tmessages.26 <= process_NLSFs.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile arm : tmessages.26 <= stereo_LR_to_MS.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile arm : tmessages.26 <= stereo_MS_to_LR.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile arm : tmessages.26 <= check_control_input.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile arm : tmessages.26 <= control_SNR.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile arm : tmessages.26 <= init_encoder.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile arm : tmessages.26 <= control_codec.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile arm : tmessages.26 <= A2NLSF.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile arm : tmessages.26 <= ana_filt_bank_1.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile arm : tmessages.26 <= biquad_alt.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile arm : tmessages.26 <= bwexpander_32.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile arm : tmessages.26 <= bwexpander.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile arm : tmessages.26 <= debug.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile arm : tmessages.26 <= decode_pitch.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile arm : tmessages.26 <= inner_prod_aligned.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile arm : tmessages.26 <= lin2log.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile arm : tmessages.26 <= log2lin.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile arm : tmessages.26 <= LPC_analysis_filter.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile arm : tmessages.26 <= LPC_inv_pred_gain.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile arm : tmessages.26 <= table_LSF_cos.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile arm : tmessages.26 <= NLSF2A.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile arm : tmessages.26 <= NLSF_stabilize.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile arm : tmessages.26 <= NLSF_VQ_weights_laroia.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile arm : tmessages.26 <= pitch_est_tables.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile arm : tmessages.26 <= resampler.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile arm : tmessages.26 <= resampler_down2_3.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile arm : tmessages.26 <= resampler_down2.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile arm : tmessages.26 <= resampler_private_AR2.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile arm : tmessages.26 <= resampler_private_down_FIR.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile arm : tmessages.26 <= resampler_private_IIR_FIR.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile arm : tmessages.26 <= resampler_private_up2_HQ.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile arm : tmessages.26 <= resampler_rom.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile arm : tmessages.26 <= sigm_Q15.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile arm : tmessages.26 <= sort.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile arm : tmessages.26 <= sum_sqr_shift.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile arm : tmessages.26 <= stereo_decode_pred.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile arm : tmessages.26 <= stereo_encode_pred.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile arm : tmessages.26 <= stereo_find_predictor.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile arm : tmessages.26 <= stereo_quant_pred.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile arm : tmessages.26 <= LPC_fit.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile arm : tmessages.26 <= LTP_analysis_filter_FIX.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile arm : tmessages.26 <= LTP_scale_ctrl_FIX.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile arm : tmessages.26 <= corrMatrix_FIX.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile arm : tmessages.26 <= encode_frame_FIX.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile arm : tmessages.26 <= find_LPC_FIX.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile arm : tmessages.26 <= find_LTP_FIX.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile arm : tmessages.26 <= find_pitch_lags_FIX.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile arm : tmessages.26 <= find_pred_coefs_FIX.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile arm : tmessages.26 <= noise_shape_analysis_FIX.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile arm : tmessages.26 <= process_gains_FIX.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile arm : tmessages.26 <= regularize_correlations_FIX.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile arm : tmessages.26 <= residual_energy16_FIX.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile arm : tmessages.26 <= residual_energy_FIX.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile arm : tmessages.26 <= warped_autocorrelation_FIX.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile arm : tmessages.26 <= apply_sine_window_FIX.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile arm : tmessages.26 <= autocorr_FIX.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile arm : tmessages.26 <= burg_modified_FIX.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile arm : tmessages.26 <= k2a_FIX.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile arm : tmessages.26 <= k2a_Q16_FIX.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile arm : tmessages.26 <= pitch_analysis_core_FIX.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile arm : tmessages.26 <= vector_ops_FIX.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile arm : tmessages.26 <= schur64_FIX.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile arm : tmessages.26 <= schur_FIX.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile arm : tmessages.26 <= bands.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile arm : tmessages.26 <= celt.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile arm : tmessages.26 <= celt_encoder.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile arm : tmessages.26 <= celt_decoder.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile arm : tmessages.26 <= cwrs.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile arm : tmessages.26 <= entcode.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile arm : tmessages.26 <= entdec.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile arm : tmessages.26 <= entenc.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile arm : tmessages.26 <= kiss_fft.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile arm : tmessages.26 <= laplace.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile arm : tmessages.26 <= mathops.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile arm : tmessages.26 <= mdct.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile arm : tmessages.26 <= modes.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile arm : tmessages.26 <= pitch.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile arm : tmessages.26 <= celt_lpc.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile arm : tmessages.26 <= quant_bands.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile arm : tmessages.26 <= rate.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile arm : tmessages.26 <= vq.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile arm : tmessages.26 <= armcpu.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile arm : tmessages.26 <= arm_celt_map.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile arm : tmessages.26 <= bitwise.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile arm : tmessages.26 <= framing.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile arm : tmessages.26 <= info.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile arm : tmessages.26 <= internal.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile arm : tmessages.26 <= opusfile.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile arm : tmessages.26 <= stream.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ arm : tmessages.26 <= compare_common.cc
[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ arm : tmessages.26 <= compare_gcc.cc
[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ arm : tmessages.26 <= compare_neon64.cc
[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ arm : tmessages.26 <= compare_win.cc
[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ arm : tmessages.26 <= compare.cc
[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ arm : tmessages.26 <= convert_argb.cc
[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ arm : tmessages.26 <= convert_from_argb.cc
[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ arm : tmessages.26 <= convert_from.cc
[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ arm : tmessages.26 <= convert_jpeg.cc
[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ arm : tmessages.26 <= convert_to_argb.cc
[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ arm : tmessages.26 <= convert_to_i420.cc
[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ arm : tmessages.26 <= convert.cc
[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ arm : tmessages.26 <= cpu_id.cc
[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ arm : tmessages.26 <= mjpeg_decoder.cc
[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ arm : tmessages.26 <= mjpeg_validate.cc
[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ arm : tmessages.26 <= planar_functions.cc
[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ arm : tmessages.26 <= rotate_any.cc
[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ arm : tmessages.26 <= rotate_argb.cc
[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ arm : tmessages.26 <= rotate_common.cc
[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ arm : tmessages.26 <= rotate_gcc.cc
[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ arm : tmessages.26 <= rotate_mips.cc
[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ arm : tmessages.26 <= rotate_neon64.cc
[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ arm : tmessages.26 <= rotate_win.cc
[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ arm : tmessages.26 <= rotate.cc
[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ arm : tmessages.26 <= row_any.cc
[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ arm : tmessages.26 <= row_common.cc
[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ arm : tmessages.26 <= row_gcc.cc
[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ arm : tmessages.26 <= row_mips.cc
[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ arm : tmessages.26 <= row_neon64.cc
[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ arm : tmessages.26 <= row_win.cc
[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ arm : tmessages.26 <= scale_any.cc
[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ arm : tmessages.26 <= scale_argb.cc
[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ arm : tmessages.26 <= scale_common.cc
[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ arm : tmessages.26 <= scale_gcc.cc
[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ arm : tmessages.26 <= scale_mips.cc
[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ arm : tmessages.26 <= scale_neon64.cc
[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ arm : tmessages.26 <= scale_win.cc
[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ arm : tmessages.26 <= scale.cc
[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ arm : tmessages.26 <= video_common.cc
[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ arm : tmessages.26 <= compare_neon.cc
[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ arm : tmessages.26 <= rotate_neon.cc
[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ arm : tmessages.26 <= row_neon.cc
[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ arm : tmessages.26 <= scale_neon.cc
[armeabi-v7a] Compile arm : tmessages.26 <= jni.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile arm : tmessages.26 <= audio.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile arm : tmessages.26 <= utils.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile arm : tmessages.26 <= image.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile arm : tmessages.26 <= video.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ arm : tmessages.26 <= gifvideo.cpp
[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ arm : tmessages.26 <= SqliteWrapper.cpp
[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ arm : tmessages.26 <= TgNetWrapper.cpp
[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ arm : tmessages.26 <= NativeLoader.cpp
In file included from ./jni/breakpad/client/linux/minidump_writer/linux_dumper.h:43:0,
from ./jni/breakpad/client/linux/minidump_writer/minidump_writer.h:41,
from E:/Telegram/TMessagesProj/jni/./breakpad/client/linux/handler/exception_handler.h:42,
from E:/Telegram/TMessagesProj/jni/./NativeLoader.cpp:3:
./jni/breakpad/common/android/include/link.h:46:8: error: redefinition of 'struct r_debug'
struct r_debug {
^
In file included from ./jni/breakpad/common/android/include/link.h:35:0,
from ./jni/breakpad/client/linux/minidump_writer/linux_dumper.h:43,
from ./jni/breakpad/client/linux/minidump_writer/minidump_writer.h:41,
from E:/Telegram/TMessagesProj/jni/./breakpad/client/linux/handler/exception_handler.h:42,
from E:/Telegram/TMessagesProj/jni/./NativeLoader.cpp:3:
e:\androidprojects\android\androidsdk\ndk-bundle\sysroot\usr\include\link.h:77:8: error: previous definition of 'struct r_debug'
struct r_debug {
^
In file included from ./jni/breakpad/client/linux/minidump_writer/linux_dumper.h:43:0,
from ./jni/breakpad/client/linux/minidump_writer/minidump_writer.h:41,
from E:/Telegram/TMessagesProj/jni/./breakpad/client/linux/handler/exception_handler.h:42,
from E:/Telegram/TMessagesProj/jni/./NativeLoader.cpp:3:
./jni/breakpad/common/android/include/link.h:57:8: error: redefinition of 'struct link_map'
struct link_map {
^
In file included from ./jni/breakpad/common/android/include/link.h:35:0,
from ./jni/breakpad/client/linux/minidump_writer/linux_dumper.h:43,
from ./jni/breakpad/client/linux/minidump_writer/minidump_writer.h:41,
from E:/Telegram/TMessagesProj/jni/./breakpad/client/linux/handler/exception_handler.h:42,
from E:/Telegram/TMessagesProj/jni/./NativeLoader.cpp:3:
e:\androidprojects\android\androidsdk\ndk-bundle\sysroot\usr\include\link.h:68:8: error: previous definition of 'struct link_map'
struct link_map {
^
make: *** [E:/Telegram/TMessagesProj/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/armv7/debug/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs-debug/tmessages.26/./NativeLoader.o] Error 1
Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

Comment: did you solve this?

Comment: Hi yes,  I finally made it after changing NDK version to r14b, get the newest source code, and update git submodule update --init --recursive, rebuild the jni files with this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/34323758/7531970, putting APP ID and Hockey Mask ID

Answer (score 5):

the problem comes from `redefinition of 'struct'`
try to change `NDK` version to `r14b`

go to [NDK Archives](https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/older_releases.html) and download the `r14b` version then extract it,

```
go to file> Project Structure> SDK location > android NDK location
```

and change it to the ndk-bundle folder you downloaded

Comment: Hi thank you for your reply, but I don't know how to change the NDK version ? Please help me how to change the NDK version to r14b, currently my NDK is 15

Comment: Hi sorry just replied you I have been busy with projects, just re try it again and I finally made it after changing NDK version to r14b, get the newest source code, and update git submodule update --init --recursive, rebuild the jni files with this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/34323758/7531970, putting APP ID and Hockey Mask ID

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have multiple includes (link.h in at least two places; and linux_dumper.h) trying to define structs that are already defined.

If you're okay with modifying the code, I recommend you try adding `#ifndef` guards around `r_debug` and `link_map` struct definitions. Like so:

```
#ifndef R_DEBUG
#define R_DEBUG
  struct r_debug {
    ...
  }
#endif

#ifndef LINK_MAP
#define LINK_MAP
  struct link_map {
    ...
  }
#endif
```